# Confusion on byte streams

Tags: java, file, stream

While reading a Java book on byte streams, I came across this example which the book uses to show the difference between the two. The example used is the number 199. According to the book, if this number is written to character stream, then it is written as three different characters: 0x31 0xC7 0x39. But if this is written to byte stream, it is written as single value 0xC7. My doubt is, 199 does not fit into a byte in Java. So, shouldn't it be written as two bytes instead of one? Is 199 written as 1 byte or two bytes in binary streams?

Comment: For these purposes, a byte is unsigned, so it is in the range `0–255`

Comment: byte is signed in Java, isn't it? How can it be unsigned?

Comment: A _byte_ is just 8 bits of data: you can regard it as a number between 0 and 255 even if the Java `byte` type would regard it differently.

Comment: We can write negative numbers to byte streams, right? So, how does that work if we treat byte as a number between 0 and 255?

Comment: Could you post the particular piece of code you're asking about?

Comment: No code. Like I said, I am just reading a book and it gives the above example (as a description, not code) which I have a problem with. Is 199 written as single byte or two bytes in byte streams? That is the question I have.

Answer (score 1):

If you call [`OutputStream.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int)), which is a method for writing a single byte, it will ignore all the bits except the bottom eight. That means that `199` and `-57` would be written exactly the same way. For that particular method, that's the way it works because it is only supposed to write a byte.

If you called some other method, it will work differently. For instance, [`DataOutputStream.writeInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)) writes an integer as four bytes, because that's what that method is for.

Comment: I just tried this code: `int n = 199;
        OutputStream f3 = new FileOutputStream("file4.txt");
        f3.write(n);` and yes, it is writing 0xC7 which like you said is -57. So, is it possible to write 199 itself using byte stream (not DataOutputStream)? I mean without 199 getting corrupted.

Comment: You could write two bytes if that's what you want. How you read them back will determine if you regard them as two numbers of one byte each or one number of two bytes (a `short`).